# Methods to find ssl encryption key on windows

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, wireshark

I must see the traffic from an android phone to a secure server using wireshark on Windows.

All packets are encrypted with ssl but i don't have the key, how can i find it?

Thanks

Comment: The key will only be on the Android device.  SSL is designed to prevent what you are trying to casually do.  Of course, if  you can locate and extract the key from the Android device, you should be able to pull that into Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

The key will be on the server. It depends on what software the server is running as to where the key will be stored or in what format. If it's an Apache server, then look in the ssl.conf file for `SSLCertificateKeyFile`. (Depending on the configuration, this may actually be stored in a different configuration file, you can grep for the string.)

Once you have the file, you can add it to Wireshark under the "SSL" protocol preferences. For more, see the [SSL page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) on the wireshark wiki.

If you only have access to the client, it's possible to decrypt traffic using the [pre-master secret](http://www.root9.net/2012/11/ssl-decryption-with-wireshark-private.html), but it's a lot more inconvenient and you generally need to rework your client software to output it (and then it's only useful for that specific session; and if you have that, you might as well just have the client log its traffic in most cases). If this is your case, and you have a mechanism to get the software to output its pre-master secret (or can modify the software to do so), I can update the answer with more on that scenario. But if at all possible, avoid it and use the server's private key.

If you have lack privileged access to the client or the server, this is by-design not a solvable problem.